# inflating variable := `find . -name 'Top' -type d`

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm currently trying to code a variable in a makefile so that finds a specific directory and then strips off the last directory name.  Currently when I echo ${variable} it inflates correctly, but when I echo ${myvar} it doesn't inflate at all!  Also!  When I use "variable := etc" it inflates to "./Top" instead of "./source/Top"

```
DESIRED FLOW:
variable = `find /username/mcarlis -maxdepth 2 -name 'Top' -type d` 
newvar = $(subst /Top,,${variable})

Example:
Variable should return /username/mcarlis/source/Top
newvar should become /username/mcarlis/source
```

Thanks!
-Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make doesn't support backquotes.  The shell supports backquotes.  When you write this:

```
variable = `find /username/mcarlis -maxdepth 2 -name 'Top' -type d`
```

you've assigned the literal string:

```
`find /username/mcarlis -maxdepth 2 -name 'Top' -type d`
```

to the variable `variable`.  Then in the next line you try to subst the value `/Top`, but that string has no value `/Top`, so the subst has no effect.

The reason it *looks* right is that when you write a rule like this:

```
all:
        echo ${variable}
```

make runs the shell command:

```
echo `find /username/mcarlis -maxdepth 2 -name 'Top' -type d`
```

and the *shell* will handle the backquotes for you.  If you look at the output that make prints, you'll see the above, and it should be obvious that the value of `variable` is not the pathname, but rather the backquote command.

The way to do what you want, assuming you're using GNU make, is to use the `$(shell ...)` function:

```
variable := $(shell find /username/mcarlis -maxdepth 2 -name 'Top' -type d)
```

Edited to add:

There still seems to be confusion.  Maybe this will help: modify the makefile to use the `$(info ...)` function to print the value of the variable:

```
variable = `find /username/mcarlis -maxdepth 2 -name 'Top' -type d`
$(info variable is: $(variable))
```

you'll see it's *NOT* set to `/username/mcarlis/source/Top`.

You can also run `make -p` to print make's internal database where it will show you the value of all the variables... and you'll see this value is not `/username/mcarlis/source/Top` that way as well.

Comment: Then why does ' := ' return "./Top" whereas  ' = ' returns "/user/mcarlis/source/Top"?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `:=` vs `=`.  Go ahead and use `=` in my example and `:=` in your example, and both will still work the same way (your example will still not work, and mine will still work).  Please re-read my entire post: I explained in detail what was happening and I never even mentioned `:=`; I don't know why you're fixating on that.

Comment: I read your post!  I was just wondering why it would act differently!  Thanks for the help dude!